# How is pass@k metric defined for automated theorem provers if we have a verifier?

Tags: math, monte-carlo-tree-search, automated-theorem-proving

The pass@k metric was proposed to measure the percentage of successful code samples (https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.03374), but it has also been used in automated theorem proving such as https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.01344. The authors of the latter paper define k in pass@k as the number of attempts per statement at test time.

Automated theorem provers such as Lean can verify the correctness of proofs, so we can run a Monte Carlo tree search to search for the proof and let Lean check the result. In this case, how is pass@k defined? In other words, is an "attempt'' one Monte Carlo tree search until we reach the stopping criterion (e.g., time limit, max allowed node expansions)?